# Call Windows Context Menu Entry Directly

Tags: contextmenu

I need to run a selfmade context menu entry via cmd.
The command is stored in

```
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\testCommand\command"
```

and contains

```
C:\Path\convert.exe %1 test1|test2
```

The problem is that windows seems to call the program associated with the command differently the first time. I don't know why and I can't get figured out how to avoid this.
So I want to call the program myself the first time before the user can call it.

If I execute the program myself directly via cmd it runs correctly, but if Windows executes it using the context menu entry it behaves different. After the first time it runs as supposed.
It couldn't find anything simmilar using google and stackoverflow ..

Whats the matter here? Also tried to run it using

```
RunDll32.EXE URL.DLL,FileProtocolHandler "C:\path\convert.exe"
```

But couldn't add the parameters requiered ..

Please help me ..